# Internal Error: Attempt to output 65872 into a 16-bit field. It will be truncate

Tags: pdf2htmlex

I am converting a pdf file to *htmldom* using **pdftohtmlex** and getting this error:

`Internal Error: Attempt to output 65872 into a 16-bit field. It will be truncate and the file may not be useful.`

Comment: Anyone having the solution to this problem:    Lookup 'mark' Mark Positioning lookup 2 has an
offset bigger than 65535 bytes. This means
FontForge must use an extension lookup to output it.
Not all applications support extension lookups.
Lookup 'ccmp' Glyph Composition/Decomposition in Hebrew lookup 44 has an
offset bigger than 65535 bytes. This means
FontForge must use an extension lookup to output it.
Not all applications support extension lookups.
Internal Error: Attempt to output 65740 into a 16-bit field. It will be truncated and the file may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and solved the problem by running as an administrator.Open the source folder then right click pdf2htmlEX.exe click properties:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUaxx.png)

select this options then save.Thats it.